# How to access a similar shorter-name application on Gnome-Do?

Tags: gnome, gnome-do

Ubuntuns.

Is there a way to circumvent the usual navigation in Gnome-Do to a similar, shorter named application?

For example, I am trying to access "Guake" terminal from Gnome-Do but my only option is "Guake Preferences" since it was my very first point of access for that leading keyword. Can I shortcut its path to the absolute path of Guake rather than the preferred path?

Answer (score 0):

So I found that one possibility is to press the PgDn or "Page Down" button when 'Guake Preferences' shows up as the option, to access the similarly named application.

EDIT: The solution is to access the new preferred path with the down arrow key enough times until it overrides the previous one.